# Passwordless ssh2 not working, to many authentication failures

Tags: ssh, cygwin

Upon trying to setup passwordless ssh2 into my cygwin sshd server on my windows machine, I get the following error in -vvv mode

```
$ ssh2 -vvv -i .ssh2/id_rsa_2048_b -c aes128-ctr foobar@vm-333-333
2016-08-24 10:19:26: 6200 Broker_tcp_connect, Dst:  foobar@vm-333-333, Dst Port: 22, Src Port: -, Local username: toobar
2016-08-24 10:19:26: 1002 Algorithm_negotiation_success, "kex_algorithm=diffie-hellman-group14-sha1, hostkey_algorithm=ssh-rsa, cipher=aes128-ctr/aes128-ctr, mac=hmac-sha1/hmac-sha1, compression=none/none", Session-Id: 6
2016-08-24 10:19:26: 6204 Broker_transport_connect, Dst: foobar@vm-333-333, Dst Port: 22, Remote username: root, Src Port: 43109, Local username: toobar, Session-Id: 6
2016-08-24 10:19:26: 1003 KEX_success, Algorithm: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1, Modulus: 2048 bits, Session-Id: 6, Protocol-session-Id: C80B284B51046645A99EDD512FD3E52BEF204ABA
2016-08-24 10:19:26: 703 Auth_methods_available, Auth methods: publickey,keyboard-interactive, Session-Id: 6
2016-08-24 10:19:26: 6303 Broker_userauth_method_failure, "publickey", Session-Id: 6
2016-08-24 10:19:26: 6209 Broker_connection_connect_failed, Dst: foobar@vm-333-333, Dst Port: 22, Local username: toobar, Remote username: foobar, Uses gateway?: No, Session-Id: 6, "Protocol error, Too many authentication failures, remote disconnect"
Connection open failed; Protocol error (remote): Too many authentication failures
```

After reading "Too many authentication failures" I decided to add the following lines to my sshd_config file and restarting it to no avail

```
MaxAuthTries 30
RSAAuthentication yes  
PubKeyAuthentication yes
```

I piped the .ssh2/id_rsa_2048_b.pub file into both authorized keys and authroized_keys2 and all the permissions on my keys appear to be set correctly. The connection works when I enter a password. I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Are you using an SSH agent?  How many different keys are in your agent?

Comment: I don't have ssh-agent and can't install it on my current computer.

Comment: I checked /var/log and couldn't find anything. The sshd.log file existed but had nothing in it.

Comment: On the remote computer, start `/usr/sbin/sshd -dDp 2222` and connect to it on port 2222. This will give you ssh server debug output.

Comment: I get prvate host key #0-3: somereallylongkeythatisreallyneatandstuff

Comment: and /var/empty must be owned by root and not group or world-writable